# Uppercase first letter of a string chrashes in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

```
actualizarTituloWeb('brand name - '+seccion.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:_| |\b)(\w)/g, function(str, p1) { return p1.toUpperCase()}));
```

where

```
function actualizarTituloWeb(titulo){
        $( 'title' ).html ( titulo );  
}
```

Also tried with:

```
function actualizarTituloWeb(titulo){

        titulo = titulo[0].toUpperCase() + titulo.substring(1);

            titulo = titulo.toLowerCase();

            $( 'title' ).text ( titulo );

        return false;
}
```

and seccion has values such as 'reserva', 'ofertas' , ..

I am not really sure why is not working but this actually makes the whole script crash (can be tested in live here: http://toniweb.us/gm2 ) in IE7 and the title of the current document is neither updated,

any idea what am i missing?

-EDIT-

Just realised that the problem is in this line! why?

```
titulo = titulo[0].toUpperCase() + titulo.substring(1);
```

**Please note:** We can not use CSS here to achieve this because it will be used for the document.title

Comment: can you try taking the first character and apply the css to it say `text-transform: uppercase` and all the other characters in the string to `text-transform:lowercase`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "crash"? Have you tried `.text()` instead of `.html()`, because the title element can't contain HTML anyway.

Comment: @RoToRa i know it's not that cool to ask that but best way to see the problem is opening te website with firefox or chrome and then in IE...

Comment: @Murtaza thanks for the suggestion, that would sound like a great solution but the text won't be in the body but in the head; it will actually be the document title

Comment: @Toni: I asked, because when I tried to in IE8 originally, I didn't see any error, however I just retried it, and does produce an error now (however no "crash"). The error's inside jQuery somewhere. Have you tried a newer version? 1.4.4 is a bit ancient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JScript <= 5.7 (IE 7) you cannot access a string like an array. You have to use `String.charAt()` instead. Array-like access is standardized in ES 5.

```
titulo = titulo.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + titulo.substring(1);
```

In addition `$('title').text(titulo);` doesn't work eighter. In IEs up to version 8 you cannot set (or get) the title by the textContent of the title-element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[ 0 ].firstChild // null in IE <= 8
                                                       // IE 9 (and other browser): text node with nodeValue 'test'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

use document.title

```
document.title = titulo;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little modification of the regex pattern the expected behavior will be achieved

```
actualizarTituloWeb('brand name - ' + seccion.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s|\-)(.)/gi, function(c) { return c.toUpperCase()}));
```

Comment: because the string will be used for the document.title so its in the <head> tag

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
var str = "blah blah";
str = str.toLowerCase();
str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
document.title = str;
```

Comment: Instead of $("title"), try using document.title = str;

Comment: In the OP, the code appears to try to make the string into `"Blah Blah"`, whereas yours makes it `"Blah blah"`.

Comment: Fair enough, they can use the regex then. I was just going from the "values such as 'reserva', 'ofertas' , ..."